# Hidden Form Field - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, css, forms, validation, spam

I am trying to prevent Spam with one of my forms using the Hidden Field trick, but for some reason its not working. When I fill in the field that's supposed to be left empty, the form is submitted like a normal.

Is there something wrong with my php? (I think that's where my problem lies):
This is the code to validate the hidden field (see top of my form):

```
 if(!empty($_POST['email'])){ die('Stop Spamming'); }
```

Here's the complete php form:

```
<?
session_start();
include("verification_image.class.php");
$image = new verification_image();
if (($image->validate_code($_POST['validate']) ? "true" : "false") == "false") {
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/fail.htm'); 
    exit;
}

if(!empty($_POST['email'])){ die('Stop Spamming'); }

$to = "email@domain.co.za"; 
$bcc = "email@domain.co.za";
$from = $_POST['contactemail'];  
$subject = "INTERESTED ADVERTISER"; 

$sbody = '<table width="420" height="135" border="0" align="center" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tr>
              <td height="90" colspan="5"><div align="center">Reservation &amp; 
 Enquiries Submission Form </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><span 
 class="style7">Full Name</span></td>
              <td width="180" valign="top">'.$_POST['contactname'].'</td>
              <td width="42">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><span 
class="style7">Contact number</span></td>
              <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactnumber'].'</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><span 
class="style7">Email</span></td>
              <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactemail'].'</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="35" colspan="3" align="center" valign="bottom"><span 
class="style7">Query</span></td>
              <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" 
valign="middle">'.$_POST['contactquery'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="84" height="108" align="center" valign="middle">
 <!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="69" align="center" valign="middle"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&
 nbsp;</td>
              <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="17"></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>';
$sBodyNew = '<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
color: #4D241E;
}
body {
background-image: url();
background-color: #F1EAE4;
}
.style1 {font-size: 14px}
-->
</style>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="420" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E7D3AF" 
class="style">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><div align="center"><strong><span 
class="style1">Website Deal</span><br>

 &nbsp;.................................................................</strong><br>
 &nbsp;</div></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="32%" valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Date Submitted</strong>
 </div></td>
    <td width="68%" valign="top">'. date("F j, Y, g:i a") .'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Name</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactname'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Contact Number</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactnumber'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Email</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactemail'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Query</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactquery'].'</td>
  </tr>
 </table></td>
 </tr>
</table>
';            
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
$success = mail($to, $subject, $sBodyNew, $headers);              
header('Location: http://www.domain.com/success.htm');  
?>
```

Heres this is what I added to my HTML form:

```
<label>
<input type="text" class="email" name="email" id="email" />
</label>
```

And heres the HTML form:

```
<form action="process_advertise.php" method="post" name="order" 
onSubmit="MM_validateForm('contactname','','R','contactnumber','','R','contactemail',
'','RisEmail','validate','','R','contactquery','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
          <input name="success" type="hidden" 
 value=http://www.domain.com/success.htm>
          <table width="465" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tr>
              <td width="465" height="387" valign="top"><span class="style66">NAME: 
                <input name="contactname" type="text" id="contactname" />
              </span><br />
              <span class="style66">CONTACT NUMBER:</span>
              <input name="contactnumber" type="text" id="contactnumber" />
              <br />
              <span class="style66">EMAIL:
              <input name="contactemail" type="text" id="contactemail" />
                                                                                           </span><br />
                <span class="style66">QUERY:</span>
                                <textarea name="contactquery" cols="40" rows="8"  
id="contactquery"></textarea>
                                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="email" name="email" id="email" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="picture.php" /><br />
                <span class="style57 style16"><em>Please enter character<br />
as listed above</em></span><br />
<input name="validate" type="text" id="validate" />
<br />
<input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
</form>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

=======================================================================
Problem Solved:

Ok guys... I've tested the form again and its working now!
I'm not why it didn't work earlier, but for those who like to know... all my coding there is correct except I removed this code from my process php form:

```
$sbody = '<table width="420" height="135" border="0" align="center" 
 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tr>
              <td height="90" colspan="5"><div align="center">Reservation &amp; 
 Enquiries Submission Form </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><span 
 class="style7">Full Name</span></td>
              <td width="180" valign="top">'.$_POST['contactname'].'</td>
              <td width="42">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><span 
 class="style7">Contact number</span></td>
              <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactnumber'].'</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25" colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><span 
 class="style7">Email</span></td>
              <td valign="top">'.$_POST['contactemail'].'</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="35" colspan="3" align="center" valign="bottom"><span 
 class="style7">Query</span></td>
              <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" 
 valign="middle">'.$_POST['contactquery'].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="84" height="108" align="center" valign="middle">
 <!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="69" align="center" valign="middle"><!--DWLayoutEmptyCell-->&
 nbsp;</td>
              <td width="17">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="17"></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>';
```

This code is not necessary as greg0rie pointed out

Comment: I don't see any `<form>` in this code.

Comment: This is the backend php form - See my edit above

Comment: You're echoing html tags. This is very wrong, you're losing syntactic coloration. You could use output_buffering for that.

Comment: Please paste the whole html code for the form

Comment: @yes123 how'd you get to that conclusion?

Comment: @ Greg0rie ... I know, I don't understand why my one developer repeated the HTML, but I always just left it as is (as back then I was very new to web design)... Must I remove the top HTML?

Comment: @yankitwizzy - Please see my edit above - have added HTML form

Comment: This is the website for the hidden form field for spam prevention:
http://www.hockinson.com/programmer-web-designer-denver-co-usa.php?s=44

Comment: Its working now ... see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways your code can be code injected.
You should use filter_var function for a minimal prevent for it.
For validating email use (at least and not just):

```
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo("E-mail is not valid");
}else{
    echo("E-mail is valid");
}
```

This line of your code seems to be strange:

```
if (($image->validate_code($_POST['validate']) ? "true" : "false") == "false") {
```

wouldn't it easier this way?

```
if (!($image->validate_code($_POST['validate'])){
```

Comment: I'm not a developer, so I wouldn't know if if (!($image->validate_code($_POST['validate'])){ would be better, but I will test it out.

The 'email' field is the HIDDEN field that spammers will fill in and humans cannot see.